# CSV Data (not file) to json

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I'm working with an API via python requests module which returns CSV formatted data.  I don't want to write the data to a file since I'm trying to turn this process into a serverless function on GCP and it should be unnecessary to create a file just to be able to read it one line at a time.  The data from the response in postman looks like this

```
    "completed","email","role","first","last","title","company","AccountName","AccountNumber","City","Description","State","Street","Zip","agreementId"
    "2019-07-04 10:14:28","echosmusz1+signer1@gmail.com","SIGNER","Sam","Signerone","Title","","Sam,s Garage","654654","Cityville","Some description here, with commas.","CA","123 South Main","98673","CBJCHBCAABAAcvZGncvMUCUf9XqXr1fwCGmKctFn_qIS"
```

It may have more that one row of data but the header will always be the 1st row.

I'm able to split by `\n` but am wondering what the best, most efficient method is to return this as JSON?

Comment: If you really are *"wondering what the best, most efficient method"* is, write a few approaches and compare?

Comment: try Panda's `read_csv()` then `to_json()` and adjust the parameters to your need

Comment: Also, this question has been asked hundreds of times, even when you [search only in the  Python tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+csv+json+%5Bpython%5D). There simply *has to be* something usable in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Pandas. First read the CSV-like string and then convert to JSON:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv_data = StringIO("""
"completed","email","role","first","last","title","company","AccountName","AccountNumber","City","Description","State","Street","Zip","agreementId"
"2019-07-04 10:14:28","echosmusz1+signer1@gmail.com","SIGNER","Sam","Signerone","Title","","Sam,s Garage","654654","Cityville","Some description here, with commas.","CA","123 South Main","98673","CBJCHBCAABAAcvZGncvMUCUf9XqXr1fwCGmKctFn_qIS"
""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv_data)
json_data = df.to_json(orient='records')

print(json_data)
# [{"completed":"2019-07-04 10:14:28","email":"echosmusz1+signer1@gmail.com","role":"SIGNER","first":"Sam","last":"Signerone","title":"Title","company":null,"AccountName":"Sam,s Garage","AccountNumber":654654,"City":"Cityville","Description":"Some description here, with commas.","State":"CA","Street":"123 South Main","Zip":98673,"agreementId":"CBJCHBCAABAAcvZGncvMUCUf9XqXr1fwCGmKctFn_qIS"}]
```

Comment: @Tomalak I'm not exactly an expert w Python yet and have not done this before.  I tried a couple thing that didn't work at all as expected and was looking for some advise from someone with some expertise.

Comment: @dralsheheri Thanks!  This method worked perfectly.  I'm going to do some more testing to verify the results given some will have multiple data rows and some may have commas and apostrophes in the data but so far this works exctly as needed.  I had attempted using pandas before but did not realize I needed to use the StringIO step before the pd.read step.  Appreciate your help here.